# Are Flex charts available in the free Flex SDK?

Tags: apache-flex, sdk, charts, flexbuilder

Hmmmm...
It appears that charts are only available through the Flex SDK that comes built-in with Flex Builder. This is a problem, since I want to use Flex 3.3, and Flex Builder came with 3.2.

Eclipse is also ticking me off, and I prefer to use a different IDE (FlashDevelop).

Any way around this? And is there anything else that isn't included the the free SDK that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The charts are [only available](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/upgrade/) with the professional Flex Builder plugin. If you have a FB license, however, there is no reason you can't use the libraries with FlashDevelop.

Answer (score 4):

You can download the Data Visualization components from the Adobe website here: http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=flex3sdk - It's the download at the bottom of the page, look for "Adobe Flex 3.3 Data Visualization Components".

However, even though you can download the components, you will still need a license to use them in your applications.  The components will display a watermark over them unless a valid data visualization license is used when compiling with MXMLC.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by riaflexer, if you need the Adobe charting components, you can download those from Adobe, and install them into your copy of Flex Builder - provided that you already have a license for the charting components.

However, if you're looking for charting and data visualization components that you can use with the free Flex SDK, you should take a look at the [Axiis Data Visualization Framework](http://axiis.org/). It's an open source data viz framework that can be used to create just about any type of charting component you could think of. Also, since it's built on top of [Degrafa](http://www.degrafa.org/), it's fairly easy to customize the look of your charts. It's still in alpha, but it still seems to work pretty well so far.

Comment: Was looking for a Flex Chart / AnyChart alternative. These Axiis guys look promising.

Answer (score 1):

The flex charting libraries have been made open source from roughly around the release of flex 4, as you can see from the announcement on February 19, 2010 [here](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/flexsdk_announcements).

Answer (score 0):

The memory profiler and automated testing tools are only available with the professional version.  The test tools are still in their infancy, but they are looking better and better and every day, but are the only way to do unit testing of Flex apps.

Comment: There is actually a solid alternative to FlexUnit called fluint. It does asynchronous testing alot better than FlexUnit.

Comment: Hah hah, I was about to ask if it supports annotations, kind of confusing my languages there.  This looks pretty cool

Comment: It does actually support annotations via [Test] metadata. Nothing like you'd get out of NUnit/jUnit, but better than nothing.

Comment: The original fluint and FlexUnit projects have merged to become the new FlexUnit 4: http://blogs.digitalprimates.net/codeSlinger/index.cfm/2009/5/3/FlexUnit-4-in-360-seconds

Answer (score 0):

according to [Flex 3 SDK Release notes](http://www.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flex/3/releasenotes_flex3_sdk.html),

> Flex Charting package enhancements – Flex 3 improves the Charting package with a number of enhancements. The axis system can now support multiple axes, and the DateTimeAxis allows for work-week filtering. A new data-oriented graphics API allows you to draw data coordinates, leaving the chart to render everything in its proper screen position. There are new formatting options and added interaction capabilities for all of the existing charts. **Available only with Flex Builder Professional.**

I was looking forward to doing Flex 3 using command line or FlashDevelop, but it seems not all features are covered. 
You might wanna install Flex Builder 3, track it while it is installing to see what values it is adding to the system like registry entries, and then uninstall and remove those entries when doing uninstall... but that's too much work...