# Adobe Flex Charting SDK

Tags: apache-flex, sdk

I have Flexbuilder installed, with SDK 3.2.

I wanted to try upgrade my SDK to 3.3, so I downloaded it from http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+3, extracted to my directory, changed the project properties in FlexBuilder, and it mostly worked fine.

The problem seems to be that the Charting Components are not included in the above SDK - so any of my custom chart components do not work and the project cannot be compiled.

I'm not sure how to get around this - I assume that there must be a separate SDK for the charting components, but I have not been able to find it on Adobe's website.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055040/are-flex-charts-available-in-the-free-flex-sdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Adobe's website had the wrong links, but has since been fixed.

The 3.5 SDK can be downloaded from http://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=flex3sdk